# Make user submitted data into a link

Tags: forms, web, input

I'm a bit of a newbie and I'm scratching my head over this one.

Here is what I want to do:

On my web page, I have an input form and a submit button.

I want users to input data to the form, click submit, and go to a page that uses the data the user input as the url.

For example, if a user inputs 'bob' and clicks submit, they would go to '../bob.html'.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the task you have taken on cannot be solved with HTML, though I am not sure about HTML5. This sort of thing is generally done using Java/JSP, C#/ASP, Perl CGI, or any of a number of other options. Whatever you use will almost certainly involve a bit of programming effort and require a server running at your site.

I could be wrong, so try looking at http://www.w3schools.com/tags for a relatively complete list of HTML options. It also occurs to me that you might be able to do this client side using JavaScript. Once again you might try W3schools for some helpful tutorials or just a quick query in you favorite search engine will bring up lots of stuff to get you started. One problem with JavaScript is that many people turn it off in their browsers for security reasons.

Good luck.